# How to manipulate Spark Dataframe in R with sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark-sql, tidyr, sparklyr, tibble

I'm working on a Spark environment, and I'm trying to manipulate some data that comes as tbl_spark. The problem is I can't apply any usual data manipulation functions to it.

I've used `df <- spark_read_table(sc,"tb_krill_sensordatatable_phoenix")` to import it, and it seems successful, however, when I try to pivot it with `tidyr::spread()`, it says the method is not applicable for tbl_spark's.

What I'm trying now is to make: `df_tbl <- as_tibble(df)`. However, it's been running for hours now and nothing happened.

I don't know if I should have used another function to import it, other than spark_read_table(), or if I should convert to another usual dataframe format in R.

```r
df_phoenix <- spark_read_table(sc,"tb_krill_sensordatatable_phoenix")
class(df_phoenix)
# [1] "tbl_spark" "tbl_sql"   "tbl_lazy"  "tbl"  

base_spread <- df_phoenix %>% 
   spread(key = sensorname, value = sensorvalue)
#Error in UseMethod("spread_") : 
#  no applicable method for 'spread_' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_spark', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"

aux <- as_tibble(df_phoenix)
#this one takes forever and nothing happens
```

Comment: Yes, `tidyr::spread()` does not work. You can use `sdf_pivot`.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to do `aux <-  df_phoenix %>% collect()`  where you use `as_tibble`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try

```
base_spread <- df_phoenix %>% 
                sdf_pivot(sensorvalue ~ sensorname, fun.aggregate = list(Value = "first"))
```

to get the same functionality as the `tidyr:spread`.

You have to get the data into R, if you want to use the `tidyr` functions, which can be done using

```
df <- df_phoenix %>% collect()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Though I'm getting this error:

> base_spread <- df_phoenix %>% 
+                 sdf_pivot(sensorvalue ~ sensorname, 
+                           fun.aggregate = list(Value = "first"))
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "Value" among (sensorname, sensortime, sensorvalue);

I should have mentioned that there's also a sensortime column, which would count as a value along the sensorname columns.

Comment: The `Value` there is a place holder; replace it appropriate columns name from your data. See example [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/sparklyr/man/sdf_pivot.html). Maybe if you can provide an example question, if that doesn't help.